# NextJs - Firebase - Refused to connect to '[url]' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy

Tags: firebase, api, next.js, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm building a NextJs app, and each time I make a request to an external api, it gives an error similar to the following error:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://flagcdn.com/64x48/us.png' because it violates the following
  Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' webpack://*".

Refused to connect to 'https://flagcdn.com/64x48/us.png' because it violates the document's 
  Content Security Policy.
```

Or when I try to login using Firebase Phone Authentication:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/....' because it violates the following 
  Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' webpack://*".

Refused to connect to 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/...' because it violates the document's 
  Content Security Policy.
```

When I empty cache and hard refresh the page, everything works fine for a while and then the errors come back.

I searched for solutions but couldn't find one that worked with my project.

Answer (score 0):

A content security policy is restricting which hosts the browser can make a connection to. You should locate the definition of your policy and add flagcdn.com and [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) giving you the following connect-src directive: "connect-src 'self' webpack://* flagcdn.com www.google.com". Then you should monitor errors and see if further additions need to be made.

Comment: I was not able to achieve that in NextJs. It would be helpful if anyone can provide an example.